# SSL_do_handshake failed ( routines::sslv3 alert handshake failure:SSL alert number 40) while SSL handshaking to upstream

Tags: ssl-certificate, nginx-reverse-proxy, webflow, nginx-upstreams, ssl-handshake

I have a very simple reserve proxy pointing to custom webflow url.

A blog is configured on a custom webflow url [https://webflow.example.com] and it is working fine in browser. There is no ssl error.

My requirement is to proxy the above url to https://example.com/blog so when user open https://example.com/blog the content of webflow should appear.

Nginx proxy is one of the solution for this. I configured as below configuration.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80; 

  server_name example.com;


  location /blog/ {
    proxy_pass https://webflow.example.com/;

 }

}
```

But when I hit example.com/blog it gives ssl error as below.

> SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A000410:SSL routines::sslv3
> alert handshake failure:SSL alert number 40) while SSL handshaking to
> upstream, client: 10.123.196.124, server: linkme.dev, request: "GET
> /blog/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://172.67.4.111:443/", host: